# How to get the value of a member of a structure in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

So I've created a structure type with this:

```
llvm::StructType* llvm_struct = llvm::StructType::create(llvm_context, struct_name);
std::vector<llvm::Type*> members;

for(size_t j = 0; j != struct_data.members.size(); j++){
    llvm::Type* member_type = /*get member type*/;
    members.push_back(member_type);
}

llvm_struct->setBody(members)
```

and I'm wondering how to access the members within the struct.

I've tried using getelementptr with no luck so far:

```
llvm::Value* member_index = llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm_context, llvm::APInt(32, /*structure member index*/, true));
llvm::Value* indices[2] = {llvm::ConstantInt::get(member_index->getType(), 0), member_index};
llvm::Value* data = /*expression value*/;

return irbuilder.CreateInBoundsGEP(data, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>(indices, 2), "membtmp");
```

Thanks for any feedback!

EDIT:

Okay so the type of `llvm::Value* data` is a `%a_struct` which was loaded from a pointer on the stack. It seems from the documentation that `irbuilder.CreateInBoundsGEP(llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, llvm::Twine)` requires the first argument to be a pointer to the structure and not the value of the structure itself.

When copying the value of the structure into a variable on the stack, this error is thrown: `Expression: getOperand(0)->getType() == cast<PointerType>(getOperand(1)->getType())->getElementType(‌​‌​) && "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!"`. The pointer pasted to `irbuidler.CreateInBoundsGEP(...)` when this error was thrown was an `llvm::AllocaInst*` which was newly allocated on the stack and contained the value of `llvm::Value* data` (type of `%a_struct`) copied into it.

The IR generated right before the call to `irbuilder.CreateInBoundsGEP(...)` with the value copied to a variable on the stack:

```
define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call %a_struct @new_a_struct()
  %a_var = alloca %a_struct
  store %a_struct %calltmp, %a_struct* %a_var
  %a_var1 = load %a_struct, %a_struct* %a_var
  %memballoctmp = alloca %a_struct
  store %a_struct %a_var1, %a_struct* %memballoctmp
}
```

Besides there should be a better way to access the members of `%a_var` without duplicating it (while still supporting expressions like `a_struct_var1.member + a_struct_var2.member` in the language).

Comment: When you've said you've tried using getelementptr with no luck, what do you mean? What does the generated LLVM IR look like?

Comment: @FrankC. When irbuilder.CreateInBoundsGEP(...) is called, an assertion fails and prints this message: `Expression: isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"`. I tried to copy the llvm::Value* into a variable on the stack, but then another assertion fails: `Expression: getOperand(0)->getType() == cast<PointerType>(getOperand(1)->getType())->getElementType(‌​) && "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!`. I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong with the `llvm::Value* data = /*expression*/`, so I'm gonna look into the type data for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have found the solution.** I think I was passing the indices incorrectly or something.

NOTE: I have not tested this with members that have different data types yet but it seems to work

```
llvm::Value* member_index = llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm_context, llvm::APInt(32, index /*The index of the member*/, true));
llvm::Value* data = /*A structure value*/;

llvm::AllocaInst* alloc = irbuilder.CreateAlloca(struct_type, 0, "alloctmp");
irbuilder.CreateStore(data, alloc);

std::vector<llvm::Value*> indices(2);
indices[0] = llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm_context, llvm::APInt(32, 0, true));
indices[1] = member_index;

llvm::Value* member_ptr = irbuilder.CreateGEP(struct_type, alloc, indices, "memberptr");
llvm::Value* loaded_member = irbuilder.CreateLoad(member_ptr, "loadtmp");
```

Comment: What is `struct_type`?

Answer (score 4):

It takes some time to grasp the concept, but it is well worth investing time on it. Look at the documentation for [getelementpointer](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#getelementptr-instruction) from llvm language reference. It explains how the member access works.

```
struct RT {
  char A;
  int B[10][20];
  char C;
};
struct ST {
  int X;
  double Y;
  struct RT Z;
};

int *foo(struct ST *s) {
  return &s[1].Z.B[5][13];
}
```

Reading the member B[5][13] of the struct can be done either directly:

```
%arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds %struct.ST, %struct.ST* %s, i64 1, i32 2, i32 1, i64 5, i64 13
```

or indirectly:

```
%t1 = getelementptr %struct.ST, %struct.ST* %s, i32 1
%t2 = getelementptr %struct.ST, %struct.ST* %t1, i32 0, i32 2
%t3 = getelementptr %struct.RT, %struct.RT* %t2, i32 0, i32 1
%t4 = getelementptr [10 x [20 x i32]], [10 x [20 x i32]]* %t3, i32 0, i32 5
%t5 = getelementptr [20 x i32], [20 x i32]* %t4, i32 0, i32 13
```

I will show the direct way. Let us first create the struct

```
StructType* createStruct(Module &M)
{
    Type* intTy = Type::getInt32Ty(M.getContext());
    Type* charTy = Type::getInt8Ty(M.getContext());
    Type* doubleTy = Type::getDoubleTy(M.getContext());

    auto* _B = ArrayType::get(intTy, 20);
    auto*  B = ArrayType::get(_B, 10);
    auto* RT = StructType::create("struct.RT", charTy, B, charTy);
    auto* ST = StructType::create("struct.ST", intTy, doubleTy, RT);

    RT->dump();
    ST->dump();
    return ST;
}
```

Now we can use gep to access the struct, but first we need a vector of Values* to store the indices to access to a particular gep address

```
template <size_t N>
std::vector<Value*> getIndex(Module &M, int (&dims)[N])
{
    std::vector<Value*> idx;
    for (auto i : dims)
    {
        idx.push_back(ConstantInt::get(M.getContext(), APInt(32, i, true)));
    }
    for (auto i : idx)
    {
        i->dump();
    }
    return idx;
}

void doGEP(Module &M)
{
    auto* structInst = createStruct(M);
    auto* structGlobVar = new GlobalVariable(M, structInst, true, GlobalVariable::ExternalLinkage, UndefValue::get(structInst), "_structGV", nullptr, GlobalVariable::ThreadLocalMode::NotThreadLocal, 0, true);
    structGlobVar->dump();
    int dims[] = {1, 2, 1, 5, 13};
    std::vector<Value*> indx = getIndex(M, dims);
    auto* gepInst = builder.CreateGEP(structGlobVar, indx);
    gepInst->dump();
}
```

will generate output:

```
%struct.RT = type { i8, [10 x [20 x i32]], i8 }
%struct.ST = type { i32, double, %struct.RT }
i32 1
i32 2
i32 1
i32 5
i32 13
@_structGV = externally_initialized constant %struct.ST undef
i32* getelementptr (%struct.ST, %struct.ST* @_structGV, i32 1, i32 2, i32 1, i32 5, i32 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old but still has many views so here's is a simpler and more efficient way to get the value of a structure member using the `CreateExtractValue` method. It avoids storing the whole structure in memory using `CreateStore` then reloading the member that you need. Your code above would look something like this:

```cpp
std::vector<llvm::Value*> indices(1);
indices[0] = index;
llvm::Value* memberValue = irbuilder.CreateExtractValue(data, indices);
```

Hope this helps